# Travar botões do celular, pelo android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Eu estou com uma dúvida. Gostaria de ao pressionar um botão no layout criado no Android Studio, conseguisse travar os botões do celular(volume e liga/desliga). E que ele só voltasse ao normal, depois de eu pressionar outro botão na tela ou digitasse um código. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Muito obrigado!

Eu estou usando o Android Studio 3.1.3